Flutter go_router context.goNamed vs context.go for redirecting to an error page
Using go_router: 14.3.0
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class ErrorPage extends StatelessWidget {
const ErrorPage({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Error')),
    body: const Center(
        child: Text(
        '404 - Page Not Found',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
    ),
    );
}
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
const HomePage({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home')),
    body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
            context.goNamed('/non-existent'); // This doesn't works
            // context.go('/non-existent'); // This works
        },
        child: const Text('Go to Non-Existent Page'),
        ),
    ),
    );
}
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
    ),
    ],
    errorBuilder: (context, state) => const ErrorPage(),
);

MyApp({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
    routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,
    routeInformationProvider: _router.routeInformationProvider,
    routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
    );
}
}

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

Above is the sample code. In the HomePage when the button is pressed, if

context.go is used then it is being redirected to the ErrorPage as defined in the router configuration.
context.goNamed is used then it is raising the exception unknown route name: /non-existent. Is it possible to route this to ErrorPage also instead of raising the exception or handling the exception in the goRouter ?


Ha, seems like it is an open issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117449

@Nguyenfamily Are you aware of any alternate way to solve this problem ? I see some one else asking the same question just a couple of months back. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117449#issuecomment-2273451139

no idea mate. Why don't you just use context.go()?

Yes, currently using the same.
